# Spring Boot Actuator Management Endpoint Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Question: how can I handle exceptions thrown in MVC endpoints in management context?

```java
public class MyMvcEndpoints extends EndpointMvcAdapter {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/foo", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Foo foo() {
        throw new FooNotFound("Foo Not Found!");
    }
}

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class FooNotFound extends RuntimeException {
    public NotFoundException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

With the current configuration, I receive `500` instead of `404`. I tried usual approaches for exception handling like ControllerAdvice, ExceptionHandler methods, etc. No success.
I also found `CompositeHandlerExceptionResolver` in `EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration` which is responsible for exception handling. I tried to define my own `HandlerExceptionResolver` bean but it cannot find my resolver in management context.

Comment: This looks like it should work as-is. Some of Spring Boot's own endpoints use `@ResponseStatus` on an exception. [Here's one example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/52536dc291da1b3417f465d73b72d60011b53fda/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.java#L122). There must be something more to what you're doing that you haven't shown.

Comment: Interestingly before posting the question, I had tested the exact code you sent to see how it works: It also returns `500`.

Comment: @Rad could you able to find any solution? I having the exact same issue. Using Spring boot 1.5.6

Comment: No. I had to handle it directly using request/response object :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Controller Advice. Spring’s `@ControllerAdvice` annotation is a specialized form of `@Component` that exists to handle cross cutting concerns for controllers. The most common use case is to provide exception handlers, but it can do a few other neat things as well.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView exception(Exception e) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("exception");
        mav.addObject("name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());

        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as stated in the question, it's not working, meaning the controller advice does not handle exception thrown by MVC endpoints.

Comment: By default, ControllerAdvice will apply to all classes that use the Controller annotation (which extends to classes using RestController)

Comment: @Rad did you find a solution to this eventually, I am having exact same issue

Comment: No. I had to handle it directly using request/response object :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Spring can't detect your Exception. So, one GlobalException class needs to be created with the `@ControllerAdvice` and then put your exception in this. Something looks like:

```
public class FooNotFound extends RuntimeException {
    public NotFoundException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(FooNotFound.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus. NOT_FOUND, reason="Not found")
    public String handleFooNotFound(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){
        //'SOME CODE HERE'
        return "user_notfound";
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as stated in the question, it's not working, meaning the controller advice does not handle exception thrown by MVC endpoints.

Comment: It's interesting. I've tested the same code as yours and it's working fine. :)

Comment: Could you please upload the project to GitHub so that I can compare with my project. Thanks.

Comment: But it's just a normal spring web app. It's not what I'm trying to do. My controller is not a normal one, it's in management context. I explained it in the question.

Comment: Can you share your github of the current issue?! As my previous answer, whatever your controller is, just to make sure the @ControllerAdvice is effected and that will help to wrap the exception.